# File not found after import a swift lib by cocoaPod in objective - c project

Tags: objective-c, swift, mixed

I am working on an Objective-C/Swift mixed project(created by Objective-c) , and today i'm trying to add a new swift lib by cocoaPod , into my Objective-C project.

here's the code in my podfile :

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'lxd' do

    #objective - c lib
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'WMPageController'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'MJRefresh'
    pod 'MJExtension'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'BlocksKit'
    pod 'Masonry'
    pod 'UMengSocialCOM', '~> 5.2.1'
    pod 'EaseMobSDK'
    pod 'UMengAnalytics-NO-IDFA'
    pod 'pop'

    #swift lib
    pod 'Alamofire'

end
```

than , i run pod install, everything is fine , install successfully. but when i compile my project , some error show up:

first it say i should turn some imports like:`#import <UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to  `"UIImageView+WebCache.h"` , than it says can't find the file UIImageView+WebCache.h .

so how can i fix this ? thanks~

Comment: where is this error showing in AFNetworking?